# How to introduce multiple outfits in a short amount of time?

Tags: fiction, fantasy

I have seven main characters, each with a different role and outfit. They get their equipment from one shop, and go adventuring soon after. How do I explain each outfit without making it sound like a fashion lineup?

Also, I'll be doing similar things multiple times. Do you know how I can do that a couple times a book?

Comment: I've noticed you ask a lot of questions that are things I might want to answer.  But you choose your "best answer" before the virtual ink is even dry.  If you wait a full 24 or 48 hours, you'll likely get more answers.

Comment: Sorry, doing it for the rep.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you wait a full day or two to see what answers develop and then choose your favorite.  Remember, you get 2 points every time you choose a best answer, but you get 5 points every time your question is upvoted.    And you're more likely to get upvotes if the question is still "open."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this the same way you introduce multiple characters: slowly over time and as needed.  If you give the reader too much information up front, they will not remember it.  It's hard to remember a lot of details before you can even tell the characters apart.  To you they're individuals with their own personalities and life stories.  To the reader, they're a crowd.

So go ahead and describe some of the purchases but refer back to them in later chapters, when relevant to the character and plot.  You don't even have to say who purchased what in that shop-outing chapter.  Use it for the reader to know what clothing and equipment are like in your world.  Wait for later chapters to connect it to specific characters.

And save some details for later too.  Like maybe the shop sells the group 6 swords, 7 fighting knives, and a spear.  You can show one character picking out her sword in that scene, but just summarize for the rest.  In chapter 5, another character can demonstrate (show directly, not explain) why he didn't buy a sword but just goes for his perfectly balanced knife.

Ditto clothes, shoes, hats, packs, etc.  Add in the detail as the story progresses and don't overwhelm your reader.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest grouping them into manageable sizes, making some sort of joke out of it, and making mnemonics with their names.

Here is a **very bad example**. It's only to make the point. Finding good names and strategies will take time, but seven is way too many without some memory aid for your reader.

> "I see the knife brigade has arrived."
>
> Compound looked over. Yes, Cross was right. The four warriors entering
>   the pub each carried a blade of some sort, each a different length and
>   style. "Those guys," Compound said. "They must be Shorty, Double-edge,
>   Rapier and I guess the lady on the end is Broad."
>
> Double-edge stood just inside the door and looked their group up and down. He said with a laugh,
>   "Archers? Seriously?"
>
> "*Proud* archers," Cross replied. "I'm Cross, this is Compound, and
>   our tall friend at the bar is Long."

That's bad, as I said, but I hope it illustrates something useful (it probably doesn't.) Still, you know what sort of weapon Broad carries, and what sort of weapon Long carries, even with that short treatment. Et cetera.

Same idea for garments.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll keep that in mind when I expand my novel!

Answer (score 1):

Each character is different and entirely your own, therefore you decide what they where and what they do. What is most common is to have a character do something that draws attention to something they do, and in turn, draw attention to what they are wearing.
 Also, if you don't want it to be like a fashion line-up, try spacing the descriptions of the outfits throughout the entire chapter, or perhaps have them all come in at different time or little groups.